# How to pass dynamic components to a container component in Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-components

Is there a way to pass components defined at run time to render inside of another component in Angular 1? That's a fairly common pattern for React libraries, but I can't figure out how that would works in Angular.

Here's a React example:

```
  const List = ({items, ListItem=DefaultListItem}) => {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <ListItem key={item.id} item={item}/>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  // Then later on, you'd define a custom list item:
  <List items={items} ListItem={CustomListItem}/>
```

I know about some ways to define dynamic children in Angular 1 with `ng-transclude` and `ng-include`. But these methods wouldn't work in the context of iterating through an array rendering one custom component per iteration. How would you achieve that with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this exact problem would be the use of [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive. This is an example of how it would be:

```
<ul ng-repeat="obj in collection track by $id(obj)">
    <li>{{obj.prop}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is `obj.prop`?

Comment: Obj.prop is the property of the object.

e.g. Obj = }a: apple, b: 2, 3: null } then Obj.a == apple or Obj.c == null